# Is "contact" better than "contact us" or "contact me" for a contact link (leading to contact details)?

Tags: customer-service, contact-page, user-experience

In many cases a web application's staff can slowly grow from one person to two or more persons and/or slowly grow back from two or more persons to one person.

### My problem

This issue might be grasped as petty but there might indeed be some formal `linguistics` recommendation to just use "contact" to prevent the following possible business-interaction bias (or similar):

> A potential customer gets annoyed getting an email response from a salesman when contacting a very demanded "freelancer" (the potential customer expected the website owner to be the sole responder)

### My question

Is "contact" better than "contact us" or "contact me" for a contact link (leading to contact details)?

That is to ask; is it better, by some formal (`accessibility`?) guideline or by some formal linguistics argument, to use the `<a>contact<>`,
Instead of "contact us" or "contact me"?

Comment: It depends on your persona and A/B testing on your UX writing and micro-copy. In each project for each persona it might be different.

Answer (score 1):

This is a matter of personal preference and how the owner wants to represent the company.  Many [most? ;o) ] companies represent themselves as being bigger than they are in the belief that customers prefer to deal with a larger organisation.

As for responses from the company, there is no reason (except maybe ethical) that the lowest in the company can't write emails that are sent "from" the CEO.  Again, it is all about how you wish to present the company.

Further, given how trivial it is, there is no reason you can't experiment; try `contact` for a while, try `contact me` and then change it to `contact us` and see how customers react.  I suspect you will find it doesn't make the slightest bit of difference.